# DC Motor on Oscilloscope Explanation

Tags: mosfet, dc, dc-motor, oscilloscope

I'm wanting to view my DC voltage waveform on a 90V DC motor. I'm currently using differential mode on my oscilloscope between A+ and A- to create what I believe is a representation of the dc voltage wave on my motor (White signal).  I'm trying to understand what the spike of voltage up to ~180V is at the end of each cycle. I have my CH1 connected to the negative terminal of the motor and CH2 to the positive terminal of the motor. The white signal is the math function of the differential between each terminal, which i assume is the voltage across the motor. The spike I'm referring to is the jump from 90 to 180 volts in the white signal in the image. The signal appears a consistent 90V DC as expected until the jump. Any help in explaining what is happening to the signal would be appreciated.

The motors operating on this DC controller are experiencing unusually fast brush wear. I am wanting to know what is at the output of the DC controller, and if it could be a contributing factor to the motors excessive brush wear.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: DC voltage is simply constant; it doesn't have any shape other than a flat line. You said this: `between A+ and A-` - what are these unknown points? What 180 volt spike are you referring to on the waveform? What type of motor is it? What waveform is controlling the motor to produce what you see? Where is the end of the "cycle" you refer to?

Comment: What kind of DC motor is that?  Brushless DC, or old fashioned with brushes?

Comment: It's a brushed DC motor. I'm trying to capture across each terminal of the motor, A+ and A-.

Comment: It's being driven by a KBMD-240D dc controller

Comment: You should add data sheet links (not buyer's links) like this for example: `[KBMD-240D dc controller](http://www.etc)` -->[KBMD-240D dc controller](http://www.etc). Rinse and repeat for the motor data sheet. Add a schematic showing what you've got and address all the earlier comments.

Comment: My bad, new to the forum, here is the controller datasheet, [KBMD-240D](https://acim.nidec.com/drives/kbelectronics/-/media/kbelectronics/documents/dc-drives/manuals/kbmd_240d.ashx?la=en) . I have my CH1 connected to the negative terminal of the motor, and CH2 to the positive terminal of the motor. The white signal is the math function of the differential between each terminal, which i assume is the voltage across the motor. The spike I'm referring to is the jump from 90 to 180 volts in the white signal in the image. The signal appears a consistent 90V DC as expected until the jump.

Comment: It seems to be an SCR bridge or GTO type SCR  bridge with phase control at line frequency and I see only half bridge being active. What are your symptoms ? Anything else we should know?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with new information instead of including it merely in the comments. Not everyone will notice your comments.

Comment: The motors connected to this drive are experiencing some unusually fast brush wear, so I was wondering if this DC controller could be contributing to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, this controller seems to be a SCR bridge. The SCR´s will be fired in a determined angle from zero crossing to get the desired set point in the controller. A simple equivalent of dc motor is a R + L and a EMF voltage proportional to speed. The "average" 90 V in the waveform is the EMF voltage. When a SCR is fired, you can see the positive edge. This SCR will be on until the current goes to zero. As there is an inductance in motor windings, the voltage will fall bellow the average, until current is zero. At this moment SCR will switch off, and voltage returns to the average value of 90 V (EMF of motor). This waveform is normal at low load, when motor current is in discontinous mode.

I would check smooth brushes movement, vibrations, shape conforms to commutator. Also check commutator surface, excentricity, copper dragg in segment edges...

EDIT: see simulation of half controlled bridge with values similar for motor.
[image]

[image]